# Hierarchical Custom Post Types - Show only parent on tax archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, archives, hierarchical

I have a cpt of Accommodation

Taxonomy of Region

Regions are then added like USA, Canada etc

Then for the posts:

I create a post for a whatever Resort and a child posts of whatever Hotel in that resort ( Hierarchical ) and assign it to a tax term like USA

All good and working 100% perfect

Question: when I go and view say USA

I see all the posts, both parent and child

How can I only show the parent post and not the children on these taxonomy archives?

Figured a simple pre_get_posts would do the trick, but tried like 20 variations with no luck

Suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Figured a simple pre_get_posts would do the trick,

It will, you just need to query posts that have a parent of `0`.

Assuming your taxonomy slug/name is literally just `region`:

```
function wpse_286405_parents_only( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_tax( 'region' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_parent', 0 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_286405_parents_only' );
```

Comment: Works perfect!

I seriously just yelled out right now with excitement. 

Thank you so much. 


Most awesome person of the day > Jacob